# How to understand "round up" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

In this HeadLine from NYTimes:

"Bob Dylan’s new book rounds up and riffs on 66 classic songs, Dwight Garner writes."

how is "round up" being applied there if it is only one book? the new book?

Comment: Bob Dylan's new book rounds up (collects, mentions, discusses) 66 songs.

Comment: ***to round up*** = [*to gather together,*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/round-up) ***to riff on*** = [*to speak for a long time on a particular subject, especially in a humorous way*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/riff)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ahh I think it was the "riff on" that has got me. Thank you

Comment: I didn't know that use of "riff on/off" myself until I decided to include a definition of it alongside the one for "round up". I guessed it was just a loose usage based on the (specifically *musical*) sense of *to experiment with a thing or idea, making changes that create a new and novel version of it*. Which I thought was maybe equivalent to ***explores / analyses*** in the cited context, but I see now it carries a fairly distinct *different* sense. Dunno if the preposition (***on*** or ***off***) is equally as interchangeable for *this* sense as it is for the original musical one though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "it was just a loose usage based on the (specifically musical) sense of to experiment with a thing or idea, making changes that create a new and novel version of it" I can see that only now

Answer (score 7):

**One** meaning of “round up” is to “gather together dispersed livestock,” usually cattle or sheep. That usage can be extended metaphorically to apply to gathering things that are not livestock but have the same tendency to become separated over time.

Answer (score 1):

'Round up' refers to the songs, not the book.

The full meaning of the sentence is that in one book, he gathers together 66 classic songs, and discusses them.